# Xamarin forms Bind different Model to Listview Header in XAML

Tags: listview, binding, header, xamarin.forms

How do I bind properties inside the Listview Header to an entirely different Model in Xamarin forms? I set the listview header property like

```
Header={Binding newModel}
```

and then used

```
 <ListView.Header>
     <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
       <Label Text="{Binding newModel.FullNameLastFirst}" />
     </StackLayout>
 </ListView.Header>
```

But this does not resolve to anything. I do however have the listview item model set to another model and that works fine. I have a need to bind the listview header to a separate model.

Answer (score 1):

You can do with using `x:Reference` extension. `x:Reference` allows you to use any property of UIElement into another one(we'll use `BindingContext`).

i.e:

**Your View Model:**

```
class YourViewModel
{
    public object HeaderModel{get;set;}
    public List<object> ListItems{get;set;}
}
```

**Your Xaml Page**

```
<ContentPage x:Name="page">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <local.YourViewModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext/>

    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ListItems}">
        <ListView.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
              <Grid BindingContext="{Binding BindingContext.HeaderModel,Source={x:Reference page}}">
                <!--Content goes here-->
              </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.HeaderTemplate>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
              <ViewCell>
                <!--Cell template goes here-->
              </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
          </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: This gives me a System.ArgumentException "An element with the same key already exists in NameScope      Parameter name: name". Why am I not able to assign an x:Name to the page?

Comment: .... which occured due to another fault in my Code Behind (my constructor chain called InitializeComponent() twice). It's working now, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

It is important to understand that if you can't just fill the Header-property if you want to perform data binding. To do data binding you have to add a Header Data Template.

The XAML below will NOT perform any binding. This is just adding content to the header:

```
<ListView>
...
   <ListView.Header>
      <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
         <Label Text="{Binding newModel.FullNameLastFirst}" />
      </StackLayout>
   </ListView.Header>
```

To data bind the Xamarin Forms ListView Header use a DataTemplate as shown below:

```
<ListView>
...
   <ListView.HeaderTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Text="{Binding newModel.FullNameLastFirst}" />
         </StackLayout>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ListView.Header>
```